# Two data sets one component , ngx-charts , angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I've created 1 component chart using ngx-charts in angular 2, data is being pulled from data.ts with no problem.

Now, I was wondering if I can re-use the same component I've created above and display a second chart with a different data set , let say data2.ts?...is this even possible ? can you guys point me into the right direction ? , do I need to create a directive here ? or maybe I need to pass data via property?

I was thinking I could create another component and pass a different data set as my last resource, but I'm probably going to have 10 charts total, so that's probably not a good option.

UPDATED CODE

graph.component.ts

```
some imports ...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.css']
})
export class GraphComponent {
  multi: any[];


  //options

  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;

  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  showYAxisLabel = true;

  xAxisLabel = 'Slot';
  yAxisLabel = 'Utilization (%)';
  barPadding = 24;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#0866c6', '#ff8c00', '#C0C0C0']
  };

  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { multi })
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, NgxChartsModule],
  declarations: [ GraphComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ GraphComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

graph.component.html

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
          [view]="view"
          [scheme]="colorScheme"
          [results]="multi"

          [xAxis]="showXAxis"
          [yAxis]="showYAxis"
          [legend]="showLegend"
          [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
          [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
          [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
          [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
          (select)="onSelect($event)">
        </ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

So, this is supposed to show on my main view component mainview.component.html

```
<section class="section">
              <div class="row ">
                <app-odometer></app-odometer>
                <app-graph></app-graph>
                <app-dateselector></app-dateselector>
              </div>
               <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xl-3"></div>
                <app-graph [data]="data"></app-graph>
                <div class="col-xl-3"></div>
              </div> 
               <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xl-3"></div>
                <app-graph></app-graph>
                <div class="col-xl-3"></div>
              </div>  
            </section>
```

Comment: You can re-use your components as many times you like. You can pass the data `<chart-component [data]="dataA"></chart-component>`

Comment: I get **Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property** I'm guessing I need to write an export class followed by an Input() method...will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I answer my own question. Since I am using ngx-charts. I didn't notice that it had a [results] option which is basically what @Erevald was suggesting. therefore the data option was already built in. so the answer was basically to add another HTML tag.

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked       
          [results]="data2"      
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

After that, modify the TS file , with ngx-chart suggestions and that's it.